# Should I make java Objects Null?

Tags: java, android, object, garbage-collection

Let's say I'm iterating over an array of Objects i.e.

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

            if (bricks[r][c] != null) {
                bricks[r][c].draw(gl)
```

If I at some point want to destroy the brick, should my remove() method nullify the object like :

```
private void remove(GameBrick obj) {
     for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        if (bricks[r][c] != null){
        if (bricks[r][c] == obj) {
            bricks[r][c] = null;
        }
```

Or should it rather set a flag `boolean exists` to false, and while iterating the objects, add a `return` or `continue` statement if `bricks[r][c].exists == false` ?

Currently I have my code based around nullifying object and null checks, but I later read about the Garbage Collector and that setting an object to null makes it run more often.

I want to know if this is true, and what I should do best to remove objects (if I even should).

Comment: If you do the latter they won't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I later read about the Garbage Collector and that setting an
>   object to null makes it run more often.

Nope, that would be pure hearsay. The best approach is to assume that the GC has been optimised to run as often as necessary to get the best balance between performance and memory usage.

Setting references to null is the way you signal to the GC that you no longer need the object. the GC doesn't have to do anything about it immediately.

**Update**

To tune the performance of an application, you have to measure the behaviour of the whole application - which means you have to write the whole application (or a very realistic end-to-end model of it) first. Micro-optimisation doesn't work.

So the best approach is to let the GC do what it is designed for - to make it easy for you to write clear, simple, easy-to-modify code thanks to automatic memory management. That way, when you have tested your app on the target machine/device and you can see where you need to tune performance, it will be easy to make the necessary changes without breaking anything.

Performance optimisation has to be driven by measurement. Measurement has to be done on a realistic prototype of the complete product. So in your first-pass implementation, concentrate on writing easy-to-modify code. Then measure, and put messy hacks into only the places where they are actually needed.

Bear in mind that they may need to be in different places depending on the device you are running on! On some devices, a hack applied in a specific spot may slow you down, whereas on another device it speeds you up. So you can't just blindly follow a rule everywhere in your code. You have to measure.

Comment: `The best approach is to assume that the GC has been optimised to run as often as necessary to get the best balance between performance and memory usage.`  How is that a safe assumption to make?

Comment: This is a game, you don't want GC to run at all (though sometimes it's unavoidable) within the game loop, especially in Android where the Dalvik GC uses stop-the-world mark-and-sweep.

Comment: Quick amendment, since Gingerbread I think it's concurrent, but there are a heck of a lot of Froyo devices out there still.

Comment: So setting it to null won't delete it from memory, but it Will shorten the time GC takes when it runs, or make it longer?

Comment: @edthethird - it's basically the whole purpose of a GC to take care of that. If you don't trust it, why use it? Instead use native code (e.g. on Android, the NDK) to do more of the performance-critical work.

Comment: @user717572 - the answer to that question depends on a huge number of factors, there is no way to answer it in general.

Answer (score 3):

> I later read about the Garbage Collector and that setting an object to null makes it run more often.

This is not true.  The garbage collector runs on a regular schedule and when the JVM runs out of memory.  By setting a reference to `null`, you can only increase the amount of memory that the GC frees, and reduce the amount of work it does, since the kind of GC used in java is O(|non-garbage-memory|).

Increasing the amount of memory freed reduces that O(|non-garbage-memory|) which can only make the JVM run out of memory less frequently and has no effect on the regularly scheduled runs.

> What I should do best to remove objects (if I even should)?

When a reference to an object is no longer needed, set it to `null`.  Structure your functions so that function calls that take a long time take as few parameters as possible.  Structure your classes so that they are loosely coupled -- one result of which is that long-lived objects have few members.  Do this consistently, and you will be in the sweet-spot for which the JVM implementors have optimized.

Comment: Note that this is a game, and this is Android, so it's not using a standard JVM, but Dalvik.

Comment: @kabuko, I realize that.  The Dalvik VM uses a mark-and-sweep GC too (though not a compacting one) so the same argument applies except for the bit about O(|non-garbage-memory|).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the garbage collector running on a regular schedule? I'd be interested in reading up on that. My personal experience is that avoiding allocations and deallocations within a game loop greatly reduces the occurrence of GCs and all of what I've read agrees with that.

Comment: @kabuko, In Dalvik, I don't think there is a regular schedule.  In Oracle's JVM, see ["Tuning Garbage Collection"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#0.0.0.%20The%20Concurrent%20Low%20Pause%20Collector%7Coutline) which says "Applications using RMI refer to objects in other virtual machines. Garbage can't be collected in these distributed applications without occasional local collection, so RMI forces periodic full collection. The frequency of these collections can be controlled with properties."

Comment: Which is why I mentioned Dalvik in my first comment. :) Thanks for the link though. I've seen that doc before but should probably read through it completely sometime.

Comment: @kabuko, Yeah.  I've seen people advocating aggressive pre-allocation and instance pooling to avoid GC in Dalvik, and that sounds reasonable.  That question is independent though of whether code outside the pool nulls references on release back to the pool.

Comment: @kabuko, Somewhat off topic: Personally, I would like to see Java allow overloading of the `new` operator even though I'm generally skeptical of operator overloading without concomitant contracts.

Answer (score 2):

You want to prevent as much GC time as possible in a game.  Don't null them, make a pool, flag dead ones, and instead of instantiating new ones, pick a dead one from the pool and revive it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set the references to null. That will cause the Garbage Collector to free more memory for your application. Setting references to null doesn't cause the Garbage Collector to run more often, but it will certainly help it to free more memory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to depend on your particular code, but in general for an android game, you want to avoid as much garbage collection and object creation as possible (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) for some details).

Do you know the maximum number rows and columns of bricks you'll have? Will you be destroying and creating bricks very often? If so, you might be best Allocating all your bricks up front, and using a boolean to indicate if the brick is live or not.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the position r/c inside the brick when you attach it to the `bricks` container. Then you don't have to search, just look inside the brick. This assumes that you can add the brick at most once to the container.

Do set the reference to null in all cases where the containing object lives longer than the scope of your code. It is not required to set to null local variables, this will be implicit at the end of the scope (end of block "}").

Answer (score 0):

First off, to answer your question directly: there's nothing inherently wrong with setting that reference to null. *Note that you're not really setting the object to null, you're setting the reference to the object to null, (or if you want to be pedantic, the value of the reference to the object)*

Whether it's a good idea or not in your particular case is a different story. You can certainly minimize garbage collection by not allocating or releasing objects (see [this Google I/O presentation](http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/WritingRealTimeGamesforAndroid.pdf)). I'd be interested in seeing evidence to the contrary from others who seem to disagree. If your 2D array is the only reference to the bricks, then setting it to null would be dereferencing the object. While dereferencing a object *may* not make GC run more often (I'm not sure on that one, although all the literature I've read recommends avoiding both dereferencing and allocation within a game loop on Android), allocating assuredly will.

If your bricks are always in the same position and they just get destroyed (like Breakout/Arkanoid) then your boolean flag idea is probably a good one. In this case your 2D array is sort of acting like a fixed size pool.

If your bricks can change positions, you *could* do the same thing and swap bricks around when you move, but sometimes it might be more natural to just add/remove normally. In that case you should allocate your bricks in a pool up front and then you can null the reference in your 2D array without worrying about garbage collection because your pool still holds a reference (but you'll need to release it back to the pool first).